# Extracting Ruby code from view into a Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some ruby code in a view and it works great but I know that's not the correct way to do it so want to put it into a helper method (thanks @SimoneCarletti). I'm having some difficulty with that and usually I find people on here 10000x smarter than me who are excellent Rubyists.

Here is the code that I want to put into a helper

```
product_feed_item.voters_who_voted.map(&:full_name).join(("<br />").html_safe)
```

Here is the method below in my user model to get the user's product_feed

```
def product_feed
  Design.from_users_followed_by(self).to_a.concat Product.from_users_followed_by(self).to_a
end
```

The controller for this view is

```
@product_feed_items = current_user.product_feed
@product_feed_items.sort! {|t1, t2| t2.created_at <=> t1.created_at}

respond_to do |format|
  @product_feed_items = @product_feed_items.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @product_feed_items }
end
```

and the View is

```
<%= render partial: "shared/product_feed_item", collection: @product_feed_items %>
```

Where the partial contains the first block of code I want to extract into a method.

How can I put this into a method?? If you need me to clarify or add anything to help please just let me know.

Thanks in advance for helping! Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its as simple as below unless i am missing something

```
def voter_full_names(product_feed_item)
  product_feed_item.voters_who_voted.map(&:full_name).join(("<br />").html_safe
end
```

And in your view

```
<%= voter_full_names(product_feed_item)%>
```

Comment: Awesome! I did something SO close to that but missed one part lol

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use decorator. With Draper decorators, you can wrap your models with presentation-related logic to organize.

https://github.com/drapergem/draper